# MAVEN successfully ran testcases with 0 failures then why I got this errors in output

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

My **POM.XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>qaclickacademy</groupId>
  <artifactId>Mavenjava</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Mavenjava</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
 
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>

</dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
              <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

My maven **error** output with **0 failures** in test cases" even though I added **SLF4J jars** to my libraries:

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

This is the installation procedure I followed for Maven for Eclipse software:

1. Download MAVEN software from "Binary zip archive" column from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
2. Extract zip file and copy the location of apache-maven-3.3.9:
   C:\work\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apche-maven-3.3.9
3. Go to control panel < Adavanced System settings < Adavanced (tab) < Environment Variables < System Variables (column)
4. Click “New”, then "New System Variable" window pops up, In "Variable Name" field, enter "MAVEN_HOME" and in "Variable value" field, paste the location of apache-maven-3.3.9, click “OK.
5. Now copy the location of "bin" folder present in "Apache-Maven-3.3.9" folder
   and double click "path" in "system variables", click "NEW", then paste it.

Comment: what do you mean "by even though I added SLF4J jars to my libraries"? In Eclipse? Or in the pom.xml?

Comment: The output `SLF4J: Defaulting to no-o` is not an error. It's a warning...furthermore why do you use an old Maven version? The zip can be extracted and will result in a directory like `apache-maven-3.3.9` ..the directory `Installation\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin` should be added to the PATH environment variable of your system. The `JAVA_HOME` variable should be set as welll to your used JDk...

Answer (score 0):

The Variable under 3. should be `M2_HOME`, but this is not really relevant for your issue.

The point is that in one of your dependencies the slf4j-api is referenced. In your tests it searches the classpath for an implementation and does not find one. One countermeasure would be to add logback like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The name is simply not relevant nor is such a variable needed etc.

Comment: I added this logback dependencies in **pom.xml** still it's showing a **slf4j warning** in the output.

Comment: @MichaelBevans, which warning is shown? Probably you are still missing a configuration file (logback.xml or logback-test.xml).